# Mongodb Java driver: kill running aggegation

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm atrying to kill an aggregation operation on a sharded cluster programatically. The operation is launched from Java mongo driver,

The way I've found to kill it is throw a killSessions command with the session identifier.

What I do to properly get the sessions identifier is:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = ....
mongoClient.startSession()

//call the aggregation stuff..
```

This thread keeps running, and from another thread, I use the mongoClient object to get the server session and kill it:

```
BsonDocument serverSession = clientSession.getServerSession().getIdentifier();
BsonBinary value = serverSession.get("id").asBinary();
```

Then I wrap `value`inside a singleton collection of document `[{ id: value}]` and call `$killsessions` with this parameter. I run it on top of the mongo admin db.

The result returns me `{ ok: 1.0 }`, but the thread with the operation still keeps running and ends properly on the server The result of the aggregation is written to a new collection on stage `$out`, so it seems it has no effect on the server session.

How can I kill, programatically, all the operations running on the aggregation? (both client & server side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I needed it to kill long running processes, my solution was to use the following command to univocally identify the session to kill

```
db.adminCommand({"currentOp": true, "secs_running": {$gte: 100}})
```

get the id from the result (asumming `inprog` contains only 1 operation in progress because there's no more operation running for more than 100 seconds,

`{ "inprog": [{ "lsid": {here_is_the_session_id}, otherFields...}, otherInProgOps...], otherFields....}`

and then pass the `lsid` field  (which contains `id` and `uid`) to `killSessions`:

```
b.adminCommand( { killSessions: [ {here_goes_lsid} ] } )
```

For a more confident method to get the sessionId other fields of the `inprog`array can be checked

Answer (score 1):

Once you start a pipeline it is running on your Mongo's process. `sessions` are a way to guarantee consistency with read/write operations.  not a way to kill running queries.

You want to use [killOp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/), get the operation id using [currentOp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/#db.currentOp).

Comment: Well, in this case I wasn't able to filter currentOp ids from all current Ops, so I can0t go in this way.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/#kill-write-operations specifically mentions using sessions to kill operations across a sharded cluster.

Comment: It refers to write operations only. not query ones.

Comment: In my case the aggregation ends with a write on $merge step

Answer (score 0):

killSessions works in my testing: [regular find](https://github.com/p-mongo/tests/blob/master/kill-sessions/test.rb), [aggregation](https://github.com/p-mongo/tests/blob/master/kill-sessions/test-agg.rb).

Ensure you are killing the session that is used in the operation, ensure the operation is running when you kill the session (you can kill the session prior to the operation starting which will be a no-op), ensure you pass the session in properly.

If you still have trouble provide a reproducible code sample.

killSessions does not return anything hence as far as I can tell there's no way to tell if it actually did anything. But the server logs when it kills  operations. 4.4 logs:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-06-16T15:55:06.872-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"QUERY",    "id":20528,   "ctx":"threa
d60247","msg":"Killing cursor as part of killing session(s)","attr":{"cursorId":7290821057815339751
}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-06-16T16:01:29.350-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":20706,   "ctx":"thread60247","msg":"Killing op as part of killing session","attr":{"opId":18212677,"lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"8f5474a5-8001-469b-87d4-692563f2dc0e"},"uid":{"$binary":{"base64":"47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=","subType":"0"}}}}}
```

Comment: Kill sessions returns an object with an "ok" property set to 1.0 or 0.0 to know if it went well. But the problem I originally hat was to get the id of the sessions to kill. This can't be get when you run the aggregation, at least is what I've found. I get it with runningOps thathave been running for so much time, whichs workarrounds my problem

Comment: But this code is made on Ruby right? I am looking a solition for the Java API, killind the  session from the client and the server session (clientSession.getServerSession().getIdentifier() ) didn't work for me on Java

Comment: All officially supported MongoDB drivers have conceptually the same APIs, because the APis are standardized. The Ruby code shows all of the needed operations (session creation, operation issuance, killing). I suggest you take that and translate it into Java.